# Gitlab CI Code Coverage with Jacoco Issue

Tags: gitlab-ci, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

Im trying to set up Gitlab CI. It is working, but Im facing issues while trying to add Jacoco code coverage.

My Jacoco plugin in pom.xml is this.

```
...

  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.5.201505241946</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>pre-unit-test</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>post-unit-test</id>
        <phase>test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>report</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
....
```

My .gitlab-ci.yml file is this.
    ....

```
codecoverage:
image: kaiwinter/docker-java8-maven
script:
 - mvn install -B
 - cat target/site/jacoco/index.html
....
```

However, Im not able to generate and display the code coverage. I'm getting the following error.

```
cat: target/site/jacoco/index.html: No such file or directory
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you remove the `cat target/site/jacoco/index.html` line and check if it is working. That line won't work, as it is running inside docker and you are trying accessing its filesystem.

Quickly let me know if it works.

Comment: But what is the alternative solution to obtain the coverage value for the badge?

Comment: Try using `$CI_PROJECT_DIR` instead of relative path